# pass string parameter to JNI code from Java

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am new to JNI interface, I have following code
My java code which calls runDemo() methods of JNI Code
    public class NonfreeJNILib {

```
static {
    try {
        // Load necessary libraries.
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
        System.loadLibrary("nonfree");
        System.loadLibrary("nonfree_jni");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
    }
}

public static native void runDemo();

}
```

and here is my JNI code (CPP code) which is called

```
int run_demo();

 extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_nonfreejnidemo_NonfreeJNILib_runDemo(JNIEnv * env,     jobject obj);
};

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_nonfreejnidemo_NonfreeJNILib_runDemo(JNIEnv * env,  jobject obj)
{
LOGI( "Start run_demo! \n");
run_demo();
LOGI( "End run_demo!\n");
}


int run_demo()
{

const char * imgInFile = "/sdcard/nonfree/img1.jpg";

const char * imgOutFile = "/sdcard/nonfree/img1_result.jpg";

....
...
//LOGICC
.....

}
```

Now I want to pass the parameter from my java code as

```
String  imgInFilePath = "/sdcard/nonfree/img1.jpg";

String imgOutFilePath = "/sdcard/nonfree/img1_result.jpg";
runDemo(imgInFilePath,imgOutFilePath);
```

Please help me, what changes required in my CPP code to pass parameters like above. I have no idea about JNI communication from java.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use "jstring" type :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11559207/3767408

Comment: Tip: Use the `javah` tool on your compiled Java classes to generate C headers with the correct function declarations. In your Java source, you can overload native methods if you need to; `javah` generates a unique C name for each.